# Windows Service and WPF Application Side by Side

Tags: wpf, vb.net, windows

I am developing an application using WPF (VB.NET) ,The application listens for an event (This is working fine) ,The event returns a variable that is passed to Web service when the web service response arrives , A dialog window appears showing the values from the response
These are my questions :

How do you run the listening part of your code as a windows service ?

Cant the service part initiate the GUI that will display the response from the web service ?

Comment: Services cannot interact with users as of Windows Vista ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx)). You would need a separate program to display any information. Also, what happens when no user is logged in?

Comment: @crashmstr The background service does not need authentication , It just fetches the information from the web service and should pass it to a gui .I read something about IPC where the response can be pushed to the GUI using named pipe but i wanted to develop the two applications (The windows service & WPF) as one

Comment: You can certainly do inter-process communication, but it sounds like you almost *need* the GUI running, so why use a service? In other words, does the service queue up data to display later if no one is logged in?

Comment: @crashmstr No it doesn't its more of a contact center application where once a call is routed to the user , The application listens for the event , gets the caller number and passes it to a web service , I need the listening code to run as a service so once a call comes in it can get the number and push it to the web service .

Answer (score 0):

The service could communicate with an application run by the user. Services can't show any UI components.
The way I did this:
1. Have a service application running that listens for an event.
2. The service application implements an interface which defines the methods and properties I'm going to use to communicate with the UI application.

```
public interface IMyService
{
    string MyString { get; }
    string MyMethod();
}
```

The service implements the interface AND MarshalByRefObject:

```
public class MyService : MarshalByRefObject, IMyService {/*...*/}
```

3. When the service starts, I register a channel for communication by calling these two methods in the constructor of the service:

   ```
   private static void RegisterChannel()
       {
           try
           {
               TcpServerChannel channel = new TcpServerChannel(MyNamespace.API.MyServiceChannels.MyServiceChannel);
               ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);
           }
           catch { } //To suppress exception when the channel is already registered 
       }

   private static void RegisterRemotableClass()
   {
       try
       {
           RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(MyService), "MyService", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
       }
       catch { }
   }
   ```
4. In the GUI application, I try to connect to the service:

   ```
   public void GetService()
   {
       try
       {
           string tcpAddress = MyServiceChannels.MyAppTcpAddress;
           ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(new TcpClientChannel(), false);
           _serviceApp = (IMyService)Activator.GetObject(typeof(IMyService), tcpAddress);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
         //...
       }
   }
   ```
5. If all went well, you can access the properties, methods and events of the service application.

Comment: @crashmstr Hi Martin , Please the GUI Application might not be running when the event is handled by the windows service , The windows service part handles the fetching of data as well by pushing work to its own task queue , it is when the response has arrived from the web service that it needs to invoke the GUI , How will it do that if the GUI is not running ?.

Comment: If the GUI app is not running, there is no way for the service to communicate with the user.

Comment: @I.Tyger However, if you're not under Windows Vista or newer, you could try starting the GUI application from the service (Process.Start method). Otherwise, see: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35773/Subverting-Vista-UAC-in-Both-and-bit-Archite

Comment: What I'll do is let the users launch the application then , but they can dock the main window to the task bar .

Comment: @I.Tyger Yes, that's exactly what I did in my application. You can still start that application automatically (see msconfig).